# Wordpress dFactory Cookie Notice Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies, plugins

With regard to the GDPR, in german DSGVO, I would like to use the Plugin Cookie Notice from dFactory for my Wordpress website. There is the possibility that non-functional cookies, for example Google Analytics, will no longer be stored if you refuse the use of cookies.

[Documentation of Cookie Notice by dFactory](https://dfactory.eu/docs/cookie-notice/)

Can any of you tell me which code to write? Unfortunately, I could not find any instructions on the internet. Maybe someone has already implemented something like that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did you read about that possibility? You cannot manipulate third party (GA) Cookies without their help and a client side request to that domain.

Comment: @janh Well I read about it in the link he posted. Loading of the GA javascript is delayed by the plugin until client accepts cookies, if they reject them the javascript never gets loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find a solution after trying multiple things. I just had to put the javascript code from google analytics between a php `if` condition like this:

```
<?php if (cn_cookies_accepted()) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m).{i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-#', 'auto');
  ga('set', 'forceSSL', true);
  ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I placed the code in the settings of the cookie notice plugin. There is a input box where you can put it. Or you could do it like @Tarod suggested.

Answer (score 5):

There is another way using the plugin [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/).

Just create a new snippet and use the Wordpress [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) action hook to call a function where the Google Analytic code will be executed if the cookie was accepted.

Example:

```
function do_google_analytics() {

  if ( function_exists('cn_cookies_accepted') && cn_cookies_accepted() )
  {      
    ?>
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-999"></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'UA-999');
        </script>
    <?php      
  }      
}

add_action('wp_head', 'do_google_analytics');
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer did not work for me, this one did.

I placed it in the 'script blocking' edit box of the 'Cookie Notice'AddOn (make sure to replace UA-xxxxxxx with your own ID from your Google Analytics account)

```
<script>
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx', 'auto');
ga('set', 'forceSSL', true);
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: This one worked for me, you can also combine it with `!current_user_can('administrator')` to disallow admin tracks in GA